# Windows says my 64 bit processor is 32 bit?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit

So the other day I got a different processor to replace my Intel Pentium E2180, the processor I tried to install was the Intel Pentium 4 HT 630 3.00GHz. When I went to install it the pc kept turning off I moved the heat sink to get better cooling by spreading the paste even more, then it wouldn't turn on, kinda, everything powered on but the power buttons wouldn't work and the ports didn't work, I fitted my old cpu powered everything on made sure the bios was up to date then refitted the 630 but windows said something about how I'm trying to use a 32 bit processor in a 64 bit operating system. I looked around on quite a few sites and aparently it is 64 bit so I'm not sure why it didn't work.

I hope I make sense.

Comment: Those 2 processors are interchangable. I would remove the processor and take an air can to the processor slot or blow on it. Sounds like some pins are not making contact. Perhaps when you changed the processor, some dust got in there. Since the holes are so small, it does not take much to cause an issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is true that Pentium 630 has 64 bits wide memory control, but doesn't have the full *amd64* instruction set, which is the synonim for 64bit in common language. Yes, your processor is 64bit capable, but nowadays the *64bit* means *amd64* instruction set.
Read more about developing *em64t*: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2005/08/23/intel_fixes_em64t/

Comment: This answer is not correct.  I actually have that exact CPU in question, that particular PC runs an old copy of Windows 8.1, the Pentium 4 630 [specifications](v) confirm it is indeed a 64-bit processor.  **Intel 64 is Intel's version of AMD64.**

Comment: @Ramhound then upgrade to windows 10 or boot a 64bit livelinux. I also have a prescott based p4, and i can't install any linux with amd64 kernel. It hasn't got the _full_ amd64 instruction set. Windows 8 also doesn't use the full set, to remain compatible with these not-so-old cpus. Win10 had thrown this goal. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2003/10/28/intel_prescott_contains_nonamd_64bit/

Comment: The hardware requirements for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 are identical.  I don't know what CPU you have, but I am confirming, that all 64-bit versions of Windows Vista through Windows 10 work on that specific CPU since it supports the disable bit.  Why would I boot Windows 10 x64 if it boots Windows 8.1 x64?

Comment: @Ramhound Then your cpu is not prescott based, at least it is not model 630. According to wikipedia: "only the Intel VT-x supported by: 6x2 e.g. [Model 662 and 672](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors#Prescott_2M_.2890.C2.A0nm.29)" and windows 10 requires the vt-x instruction. So you have 662 or 672.
It's not only my experiment: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/windows-10-on-pentium-4-ht.2458350/

Comment: The VT-X instruction isn't required for Windows 10; NX is the disable bit which the 630 supports; "All models support: MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, Hyper-Threading, Intel 64, XD bit (an NX bit implementation)" statisfies the requirements for Windows 8.1 x64 and greater.  PAE is prerequisite for NX this the 630 supports both and of course it supports SSE2: http://ark.intel.com/m/products/27478/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-630-supporting-HT-Technology-2M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB#@product/specifications and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors

Comment: "Your processor also needs to support CMPXCHG16b(which also, annoyingly, needs motherboard support, so it can be hard to test for), PrefetchW, and LAHF/SAHF, which adds more confusion. Fortunately, most people will have this already." I wish the PC was up and running, I could reverify which Pentium CPU I have I know it's 775 socket since I purchase it right before the first core generation.

Comment: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_4/TYPE-Desktop%20Pentium%204%20Prescott.html According to this third source the CPU can run a 64-bit version of Windows; on the other hand i realized it was the Pentium D that I had; which just by luck is the same socket and almost the same generation it just had vt-x support